# Which setting cause rip of format in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I encounter an annoying issue with Android studio. I have nicely and easy readable formatted piece of code:

[image]

But if I press Code - reformat code, my string declaration turns in complete mess:

[image]

It would not be a problem if only new line characters were removed, but Code - reformat code also split my strings and make empty line insertions (WTF)

Compare string before reformat:

```
private static final String
            DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table "
                    + TABLE_NAME + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + COLUMN_ITEM_ID + " integer  default '0', "
                    + COLUMN_SLUG + " text  default '',"
                    + COLUMN_TITLE + " text  default '',"
                    + COLUMN_TYPE + " integer default '0', "
                    + COLUMN_YOUTUBE_ID + " text default '',"
                    + COLUMN_ARTISTS + " text  default '',"
                    + COLUMN_ARTISTS_SLUG + " text default '',"
                    + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text  default '',"
                    + COLUMN_PICTURE + " text  default '',"
                    + COLUMN_SOURCE + " text default '',"
                    + COLUMN_VIEW_COUNT + " integer  '0',"
                    + COLUMN_GOOGLE_LINK + " text default '',"
                    + COLUMN_OFFLINE_SOURCE + " text default '',"
                    + COLUMN_IS_SAVED_OFFLINE + " integer  '0', "
                    + COLUMN_OFFLINE_PLAYS + " integer default '0',"
                    + COLUMN_DOWNLOADING_ID + " integer default '-1',"
                    + COLUMN_IS_LIKE + " integer default '0' " +
                    ");";
```

and string after reformat:

```
private static final String
            DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    "" + COLUMN_ITEM_ID + " integer  default '0', " + COLUMN_SLUG + " text  " +
                    "default ''," + COLUMN_TITLE + " text  default ''," + COLUMN_TYPE + " integer " +
                    "default '0', " + COLUMN_YOUTUBE_ID + " text default ''," +
                    "" + COLUMN_ARTISTS + " text  default ''," + COLUMN_ARTISTS_SLUG + " text " +
                    "default ''," + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text  default ''," +
                    "" + COLUMN_PICTURE + " text  default ''," + COLUMN_SOURCE + " text default " +
                    "''," + COLUMN_VIEW_COUNT + " integer  '0'," + COLUMN_GOOGLE_LINK + " text " +
                    "default ''," + COLUMN_OFFLINE_SOURCE + " text default ''," +
                    "" + COLUMN_IS_SAVED_OFFLINE + " integer  '0', " + COLUMN_OFFLINE_PLAYS + " " +
                    "integer default '0'," + COLUMN_DOWNLOADING_ID + " integer default '-1'," +
                    "" + COLUMN_IS_LIKE + " integer default '0' " +
                    ");";
```

You clearly can see lots of `""` which were not present before.

How to fix such strange behaviour?